# Python. Edit file with other extension, format

Tags: python, edit

I want to be able to edit file that is not in txt, xml etc format. I mean how to edit wit python a file that has xml structure and can be opened in notepad++.
I have file with extension .sdlxliff. This file can be opened in notepad++ without any problem. XLF files can be also edited in notepad. How to edit that kind of files using python.

Comment: You edit the file *like every other file*.

Comment: What does "editing a file with Python" mean? Python is a programming language, not a text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit them the very same way as any other text files, because that's what xml files are.

They have certain structure, but otherwise - they are just simple text files.